# How to tell Reflectively if an Attribute has a public Setter

Tags: c#, reflection

Im saving an object model out to XML but when i load it back in I get exceptions when trying to use PropertyInfo.SetValue() because the property doesn't have a setter just a getter.

I want to either not save out the properties that only have getters or figure out on load whether its valid for me to try and set a value or not.

Anybody know how to do this

Cheers

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [`PropertyInfo.GetSetMethod`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2ef4d5h3.aspx) - this will return `null` if either the property is read-only or the setter is non-public.

```
if (property.GetSetMethod() != null)
{
    // Yup, you can write to it.
}
```

If you can cope with a non-public setter, you can use:

```
if (property.GetSetMethod(true) != null)
{
    // Yup, there's a setter - but it may be private
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [PropertyInfo.CanWrite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.canwrite%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) property.

Comment: FYI, this will return true even for non-public setters.