# fetch datarow to c# object

Tags: c#, database, class, architecture

I have an class Item that represents an item in a list. I have in it function that calls stored procedure that returns datatable and I need to convert the datatable to Array of items.
Here is what I do:

```
public class Item
{
    private string _ItemIdDataName = "item_id";
    private string _ItemNameDataName = "item_name";
    private string _PriceDataName = "price";

    public long ItemId { get; set; }
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public float Price { get; set; }

    private Item(DataRow row)
    {
        if (row != null)
        {
            ItemId = long.Parse(row[_ItemIdDataName].ToString());
            ItemName = row[_ItemNameDataName].ToString();
            Price = float.Parse(row[_PriceDataName].ToString());
        }
    }

    public Item[] load()
    {
        DataTable dt=DBHandler.GetItems();//Stored procedure that returns DataTable 
        Item[] items = new Item[dt.Rows.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            items[i] = new Item(dt.Rows[i]);
        }
        return items;
    }
}
```

Am I doing it right?
How can I improve this?

Comment: Why is `load()` inside Item class?

Comment: Because it looks very meanningless to put it under different class. I have many cases like this one and I cannot have hundred of classes that only returns query result.

Comment: @Naor make it static at least..

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If  you're only gonna use it once it probably fine, but if you'll do it a lot you should try to do some more generic stuff. I wrote a blog post about how to write an extension method for `DataTable` that creates a list of objects. It works by the convention that the properties in the object should have the same name as the columns in the stored procedure (I would change the name in the stored procedure if I could):

```
public static class DataTableExtensions
{
    public static IList<T> ToList<T>(this DataTable table) where T : new()
    {
        IList<PropertyInfo> properties = typeof(T).GetProperties().ToList();
        IList<T> result = new List<T>();

        foreach (var row in table.Rows)
        {
            var item = CreateItemFromRow<T>((DataRow)row, properties);
            result.Add(item);
        }

        return result;
    }

    public static IList<T> ToList<T>(this DataTable table, Dictionary<string, string> mappings) where T : new()
    {
        IList<PropertyInfo> properties = typeof(T).GetProperties().ToList();
        IList<T> result = new List<T>();

        foreach (var row in table.Rows)
        {
            var item = CreateItemFromRow<T>((DataRow)row, properties, mappings);
            result.Add(item);
        }

        return result;
    }

    private static T CreateItemFromRow<T>(DataRow row, IList<PropertyInfo> properties) where T : new()
    {
        T item = new T();
        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            property.SetValue(item, row[property.Name], null);
        }
        return item;
    }

    private static T CreateItemFromRow<T>(DataRow row, IList<PropertyInfo> properties, Dictionary<string, string> mappings) where T : new()
    {
        T item = new T();
        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            if(mappings.ContainsKey(property.Name))
                property.SetValue(item, row[mappings[property.Name]], null);
        }
        return item;
    }
}
```

Now you can just call

```
var items = dt.ToList<Item>();
```

or

```
var mappings = new Dictionary<string,string>();
mappings.Add("ItemId", "item_id");
mappings.Add("ItemName ", "item_name");
mappings.Add("Price ", "price);
var items = dt.ToList<Item>(mappings);
```

The blog post is here: http://blog.tomasjansson.com/2010/11/convert-datatable-to-generic-list-extension

There are many ways in which you can extend this, you could include some kind of mapping dictionary telling the extension how to map the columns, in that way the names doesn't need to match. Or you can add a list of property names that you would like to exclude in the mapping.

**Update:** Your object (`Item`) you are creating must have a default constructor otherwise the private method won't be able to create it. Since the way the solution works is first to create the object than use the properties that you get from the reflection to set the values of the object.

**Update 2:** I added the part with mappings dictionary but haven't tried it myself so it might not compile. However, the concept is there and I think it works.

Comment: Thank you... I was trying to just keep it simple, and it isn't that hard to match your object properties against the columns in the stored procedure :).

Comment: Here you assume that db fields names are equale to the members names. What is not always true. Am I wrong?

Comment: You are 100 % correct, and I says so in the answer as well. When I implemented this I tried to keep the object properties aligned with the name of the columns to make it easier and it worked perfectly fine. If that is not the case you can change the extension method to also take a `Dictionary<string, string>` that maps the property name to column name, see update in a couple of minutes.

Comment: It is really nice but doesn't it really slow according to the the code I wrote?

Comment: It is probably slower yes, but do you have a problem with performance? Keep it simple as long as you can, then optimize in those places where you need to optimize.

Comment: Thanks, it is helping me. Please correct:      property.SetValue(item,Convert.ChangeType(row[mappings[property.Name]],property.PropertyType), null);

Comment: @Naor: That shouldn't be necessary... The `SetValue` method should handle this. Did you get an error on that? What error?

Comment: @Tomas Jansson: Tomas, I get an error when it tries to convert single to double or something like this. In the DB the field is float. This way works fine. BTW, do you know how will it works with Enums as field type (the db pass the name of the enum value)?

Comment: @Naor: The problem is that you had a type mismatch. You could change back to the old solution and instead of having a float in your object use double (double is more common to use than float). What you are doing now might cause error since the data in the database is of type double, that is, having 64 bits but your float only has 32 bits, so if the value in the database is to large you might get somekind of error... not sure what though. So change back to what you had and use double in your object instead. Also, it might work with enums... try it and let me know :).

Comment: @Naor: Just tried the enum and it does work as long as the enum is stored as an int in the database.

Comment: @Tomas Jansson: What you sais is that float on the DB is double on client? Can I use Enum as string and not int?

Comment: @Naor: What I say is that you proabably has a double type in db, but only a float in the client (or that what your example code says). Change `public float Price { get; set; }` to `public double Price { get; set; }` and also change your old code and you'll be fine. Enums stored in database will work fine **if they are int**, string enums won't work with that implementation, but it is probably possible to extend the solution to allow for that too.

Comment: @Tomas Jansson: Assuming I am using this: property.SetValue(item,Convert.ChangeType(row[mappings[property.Name]],property.PropertyType), null);  what is wrong or different from your approach?

Comment: @Naor: As I said earlier, this will even work for float->double... and I don't think that is no good since double > float (double: 64 bit, float: 32 bit). Also, this will be even slower :), the Convert will convert it and then SetValue will parse it one more time. Of course it works, but I would go for my solution :). Less code as well.

Comment: @Tomas Jasson, I have asked another question (linked) which you may be interested in.

Comment: @SBlacker, where is the link?

Comment: Nice answer, but beware properties without public setters! See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811198/how-to-tell-reflectively-if-an-attribute-has-a-public-setter]

Answer (score 5):

Pretty good, but I have a few suggestions:

- Don't cast things ToString to be
  parsed back to another type.  This
  can cause corruption of your data
  type, and is slow/inefficient.
- Expect and check for null's coming from SQL Server.

So, instead of:

```
ItemId = long.Parse(row[_ItemIdDataName].ToString());
```

Try:

```
 ItemId = row.Field<long?>(_ItemIdDataName) ?? value_if_null;
```

(Add a reference to System.Data.DatasetExtensions to get the Field extension)

Answer (score 3):

Perfect job for [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/).

Two examples:

http://house9.blogspot.com/2010/11/automapper-datatable-to-list.html

http://www.geekytidbits.com/automapper-with-datatables/

Comment: @Naor Indeed - but this was asked well after AutoMapper existed, and this still comes up in google searches looking for an answer. StackOverflow is for finding the best answers, not for ensuring the conversation ties up nicely and is then closed - if that's what you wanted, use Google Groups.

Answer (score 0):

Your private Item constructor and the `load()` functions do not seem to **belong** in your `Item` class.

You know, a class should do one thing and one thing well.

So try to
 
1. refactor out the private c'tor to a say a helper class that simply parses the DataRow and returns an instance of Item 
2. and refactor the `load()` into a different class that simply uses the above helper method and returns an array of Item object instances

Comment: This way will make me create many many classes. I want to put things together if there is a connection. I ran out of names to classes..

Comment: @Naor: I am just answering your main questions ;)