# Assign a generic classes properties with Expression Trees

Tags: c#, generics, expression-trees

Help, I appeared to wondered off the path somewhat.

After asking [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6919203/improvements-with-reflection-and-generics/6919266) question yesterday, I decided to take a look into expression trees. I found a nice little place to start and here is what I have so far:

```
  // Gets the property type
  ParameterExpression paramProperty = Expression.Parameter(property.PropertyType);
  // Gets the value from row[0] (SqlDataReader)
  ParameterExpression paramValue = Expression.Parameter(row[0].GetType());
  // really no clue, makes a property so to speak?
  MemberExpression prop = Expression.Property(paramProperty, property);
  // assigns the property the value from the SqlDataReader
  BinaryExpression assign = Expression.Assign(prop, paramValue);
  // adds to an expression list ready for compilation
  exps.Add(assign);
  // allows things to be executed sequentially?
  BlockExpression blockExpression = exps.Count > 0 ? Expression.Block(exps) : Expression.Block(Expression.Empty());
  // create the parameter array
  List<ParameterExpression> paramArr = new List<ParameterExpression>();
  paramArr.Add(paramProperty);
  paramArr.Add(paramValue);
  // get a lambda so I can compile this for re-use
  Expression<Action<T>> lamExp = Expression.Lambda<Action<T>>(blockExpression, paramArr);
```

First of all, are my comments right? I am piecing this information in the good old fashion way of a tutorial and msdn doc's.

From the bits that I have been reading, I *think* I should have been able to compile this, store it in a dictionary with a type as the key and call it when I needed to. Eg.

```
  ConcurrentDictionary<Type, ??> ExpressionCache;
  if(ExpressionCache.ContainsKey(typeof(T))
  {
         // property is the variable of a foreach loop of type PropertyInfo
         ExpressionCache[typeof(T)](property); 
  } // else do the first piece of code...
```

So in summary,

1. Am I heading down the right track?
2. Are my comments about the Expressions correct?
3. What type should I use for the concurrent dictionary?
4. When I cache the reference, how do I pass different parameters to the lambda?

Any improvements or suggestions are welcome as long as the are explained well. I am trying to understand how it works not just to make it work :)

Comment: why are you calling Type.GetTypeFromHandle when you already have the Type?

Comment: @JeffN825, shh you didn't see that ;)

Comment: Could you summarize what the expression you're building is supposed to be doing?

Comment: @Jeff Mercado, basically the same as in the linked question but an expression tree version. I have never used expression tree's so I want to learn. Any resources, or code challenges (like try and build this) to help me learn would be appreciated.

Comment: @SBlackler: What I was trying to get you to do was to explicitly state the goal in _this_ question since it's never really mentioned.  It was never really clearly stated in your linked question either.  One would have to follow your linked question to figure out what was being done or try to figure out what your code is doing.  Neither option the best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for commentary more than anything else...right?

First of all, how will you have your SqlReader at compile time?

```
// Gets the value from row[0] (SqlDataReader)
ParameterExpression paramValue = Expression.Parameter(Type.GetTypeFromHandle(row[0].GetType()));
```

Your lambda takes two parameters though...so something is wrong (Action takes one parameter).

I would think that you really want is an `Func<SqlDataReader, T>`. That way, you give it your SqlDataReader and it produces a T. So:

```
var list = new List<T>();
// get a SqlDataReader
while (reader.Read())
{
    Func<SqlDataReader, T> readRow = GetReader<T>();
    list.Add(readRow(reader);
}
```

I would store your cache as

```
 ConcurrentDictionary<Type, Delegate> ExpressionCache;  // can't use T here since each Func will have a different T
```

Then cast it to the appropriate delegate type for the caller upon retrieval (have your method take a generic parameter:

```
 public Func<SqlDataReader, T> GetReader<T>() 
 { 
     Delegate d;
     if(!ExpressionCache.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out d)
     {
         ExpressionCache[typeof(T)] = d = // build and compile lambda
     } 
     // cast to strong typed delegate...we don't want to have to DynamicInvoke...that's slow
     return (Func<SqlDataReader, T>)d;
 }
```

So...as for your lambda builder/compiler:

```
        // hang on to row[string] property 
        var indexerProperty = typeof(SqlDataReader).GetProperty("Item", new[] { typeof(string) });

        // list of statements in our dynamic method
        var statements = new List<Expression>();

        // store instance for setting of properties
        ParameterExpression instanceParameter = Expression.Variable(typeof(T));
        ParameterExpression sqlDataReaderParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(SqlDataReader));

        // create and assign new T to variable: var instance = new T();
        BinaryExpression createInstance = Expression.Assign(instanceParameter, Expression.New(typeof(T)));
        statements.Add(createInstance);

        foreach (var property in typeof(T).GetProperties())
        {
            // instance.MyProperty
            MemberExpression getProperty = Expression.Property(instanceParameter, property);

            // row[property] -- NOTE: this assumes column names are the same as PropertyInfo names on T
            IndexExpression readValue = Expression.MakeIndex(sqlDataReaderParameter, indexerProperty, new[] { Expression.Constant(property.Name) });

            // instance.MyProperty = row[property]
            BinaryExpression assignProperty = Expression.Assign(getProperty, Expression.Convert(readValue, property.PropertyType));

            statements.Add(assignProperty);
        }

        var returnStatement = instanceParameter;
        statements.Add(returnStatement);

        var body = Expression.Block(instanceParameter.Type, new[] { instanceParameter }, statements.ToArray());

        /* so we end up with
         * T Read(SqlDataReader row)
         * {
         * var x = new T();
         * x.Prop1 = (cast)row["Prop1"]
         * x.Prop2 = (cast)row["Prop2"]
         * x.Prop3 = (cast)row["Prop3"]
         * x.Prop4 = (cast)row["Prop4"]
         * etc.
         * return x
         * }
         */
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<SqlDataReader, T>>(body, sqlDataReaderParameter);

        // cache me!
        return lambda.Compile();
```

Haven't tested this, so please use with care and give it a try yourself.

I'm not sure if I got your intended usage correct...is it?

Comment: By the looks of things, you have understood correctly. I am going to test this when I get back in from work tonight. I am guessing that it's safe to move the definition of `readRow` outside of the while loop? And that I can use a similar caching technique for `typeof(T).GetProperties()` Cheers :)

Comment: Yes, of course about the while loop. There's not really a point in caching typeof(T).GetProperties if you're caching the resulting compiled delegate (you'll only be calling typeof(T).GetProperties once's per type.

Comment: Works like a charm, with one small change. Needed to change `readValue` to `Expression.Convert(readValue, property.PropertyType)` in the `foreach` loop

Comment: Its just a bit faster than the version in the linked question. See here: http://i53.tinypic.com/qs9qax.png

Comment: Good catch. Makes sense row["name"] returns an object...but you need to cast it to PropertyType.